# How to add actual number in the bar chat?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I have created the following bar chart.

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \caption{Accuracy comparison of A with other models}
  \scriptsize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D},
   ytick=data,
   xbar,
   y=0.5cm,
   enlarge y limits={abs=0.5cm},
   xlabel={Accuracy(\%)}
  ]
  \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates
    {(4.90,A)
     (5.05,B)
     (7.99,C)
     (24.67,D)          
    };
\end{axis}
\label{comparison}
\end{tikzpicture}
   \vspace{-1.5em}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

But I have to also present the actual number on top the bar. How can I do that?

But I need to get something like the following to show the actual numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
symbolic y coords={A,B,C,D},
ytick=data,
xbar,
xmin=0,
y=0.5cm,
enlarge y limits={abs=0.5cm},
enlarge x limits={abs=3,upper},
xlabel={Accuracy(\%)},
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
nodes near coords style={orange},
]
\addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {(4,A) (5,B) (7,C) (24,D)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: x bar chart with percentages]

Comment: it seems to does not work with the decimal number `4.90`.

Comment: Yes it does.   ....

Comment: Sorry what meant is if I add decimal number it overlaps with the border i.e. exceeds the border.

Comment: I added `enlarge x limits={abs=3,upper},` to move the border. You could increase it to `enlarge x limits={abs=6,upper},` or use smaller font or...

Comment: `nodes near coords style={orange, font=\small},`

Comment: Is there a way to tilt text for A, B, C, D or make the text for A, B, C, D small as well?

Comment: Thanks for the help @hpekristiansen. You are incredible.

Comment: `y tick label style={font=\small, rotate=45},`